# How to trigger event when a window changes?

Tags: javascript

I have a window that I am creating via `window.open`. This window displays a form. When the form is submitted, the user is taken to a new page: `success.html`. How can I trigger an event after `success.html` loads? I've tried to following:

```
var myWindow = window.open("http://theform.com", "THE_NAME", 
    "menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,width=500,height=463");
myWindow.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    console.log("Window event" + myWindow.location.href);
}, false);
```

No events are triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is `postMessage` between windows if they have the same origin.

Learn more: [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame/25098153#25098153) (follow link even if its about iframes/frames)

Comment: `postMessage` works regardless of origin. The windows should have the same domain by setting the `document.domain` property.

Comment: I know it works regardless of origin. But it wont work if there is no code to listen and respond.

What I meant by origin was: you being the one writing them. (their origin)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your event listener in the success.html instead of where you are doing it right now.

Comment: But I need the the function to be executed where the window is created.

Comment: In my view it's not achievable. Maybe be others can help you out.